# Is it possible to create rule factories in SASS?

Tags: sass

I've recently set to work moving some old stylesheets into SASS. I'm new to the syntax and would like to make the best use of it I can. I'm curious is something like the below is possible.

```
@function colorRuleFactory($prefix, $attribute, $named-colors){
    @each $named-color in $named-colors{
        createRule($attribute, $named-colors[$named-color], $name=$prefix + '-' + $named-color);
    }
}
```

Example of function call:

```
colorRuleFactory('bk', 'background', $named-colors);
```

Example of compiled output:

```
 /* $ColorNameA: #000000;
    $ColorNameB: #111111;
    $ColorNameC: #222222;
 */

.bk-ColorNameA {
    background: #000000; 
 }

.bk-ColorNameB{
    background: #111111;
 }

.bk-ColorNameC{
    background: #222222;
}
```

Comment: Can you give an example of input and desired output (compiled)?

Comment: @Arkellys Just added an example.

Answer (score 0):

To do what you want you can use a [`mixin`](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/mixin) as below:

```
$named-colors: (
   ColorNameA: #000000,
   ColorNameB: #111111,
   ColorNameC: #222222
);

@mixin colorRuleFactory($prefix, $attribute, $named-colors) {
    @each $named-color, $color in $named-colors {
        .#{$prefix}-#{$named-color} {
            #{$attribute}: $color;
        }
    }
}

@include colorRuleFactory('bk', 'background', $named-colors);
```

And if you want to separate the rule creation in another mixin:

```
@mixin createRule($attribute, $value, $name) {
    .#{$name} {
        #{$attribute}: $value;
    }
}

@mixin colorRuleFactory($prefix, $attribute, $named-colors) {
    @each $named-color, $color in $named-colors {
        @include createRule($attribute, $color, $prefix + '-' + $named-color);
    }
}
```